# Are there cases where Retreating awards items, other than Explore's Minibosses?

Tags: gems-of-war

Are there cases where Retreating awards items, other than Explore's Minibosses?

I know fleeing a Miniboss Battle in Explore awards a pittance of Mythstones... A.k.a 2 / 3... But I was on Level 1. I haven't tried it with higher levels yet.

As a side note, that's also a good way to avoid Mythic Bosses if you want to...

But... **are there other situations where Retreating is slightly useful**, a.k.a actually gives rewards, instead of just avoiding a fight?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, retreating from a battle rewards you nothing at all, so it's even worse than losing a battle. In my opinion, the only plausible reasons one might retreat are:

1. They're stuck in a battle that's likely to run too long. This happens when dealing with infinitely respawning teams (like bandit spam teams, or Life and Death teams (which respawns giant spiders endlessly)), or infinitely healing teams (like Guardian Crown teams).
2. You are chasing the PvP leaderboard and you need your battles to be as fast as possible. Often this means that if your starting board is unfavourable, you'd retreat (with no rewards) and try again, just to save time.

Don't retreat from a Mini-Boss battle just to avoid the Mythic Boss battle. (You can simply do an explore run in another kingdom, and "consume" the mythstones in the second kingdom.)

Comment: If I retreat, I get over 100 Mythstones, and can change the difficulty of the Mythic Boss, instead of having to stick with the level if I defeat the Miniboss... Like, LV 1 Explore for Explore Fights grinding, got 100 Mythstones, but don't want to fight a LV 1 Mythic Boss.

Comment: Collect your mythstones in a different kingdom from the one you want to do higher level mythic boss in. Ideally, you'd use kingdoms that have a mythstone bonus. Then once you have 100 mythstones, go back to the kingdom you want to get the mythic boss in, at the level you want to use, and spend the mythstones there.

Comment: I've been running efficiency calculations for Arcane Traitstone Grind... I think my way is faster, but the math is tedious.